# Is there any animal, which knows it will die?

Tags: consciousness, animal-cognition

In light of the [Cambridge Declaration of Consciousness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_consciousness#Cambridge_Declaration_on_Consciousness), are there any animals, which are aware that they will die?

Comment: Some of them definitely do. Elephants are the biggest example. I will try to pull out some studies on this behavior of elephants.

Comment: Unfortunately most data I found were of the nature of "12 facts about" or brooding of pet lovers. Many mammals can identify the dying and the dead. Only elephants and whales seem to respond to aging, but that alone is not enough. Linking aging with death and perceiving aging as inevitable are difficult to attribute to animals. Fear response towards aging can be a valuable proof, but difficult to attain. All we know for sure is that elephants think about death. They have a morbid fascination towards the remains of any dead elephant.

Comment: There is an answer to this at [this Philosophy question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/4690/do-animals-know-that-they-are-going-to-die)

Comment: @Chris - perfect, thanks a lot! Spero, thanks too!